# google artifact registry dependency NoSuchMethod

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am using google artifact registry to import my dependency to another project. When I run my project locally, everything works fine, but my gitlab CI pipeline fails with the following error

```
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.DefaultMavenArtifactRepository.getConfiguredCredentials()Lorg/gradle/api/credentials/Credentials;
rt-test_1  |     at com.google.cloud.artifactregistry.gradle.plugin.ArtifactRegistryGradlePlugin.configureArtifactRegistryRepository(ArtifactRegistryGradlePlugin.java:143)
rt-test_1  |     at com.google.cloud.artifactregistry.gradle.plugin.ArtifactRegistryGradlePlugin.lambda$modifyProject$4(ArtifactRegistryGradlePlugin.java:114)
```

Can you please explain what's the problem and how can this be fixed. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

FYI, this has been fixed in version 2.1.1 of the [Artifact Registry plugin](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.google.cloud.artifactregistry.gradle-plugin).

Answer (score 1):

Turns out there is a bug in gradle version so I changed it to older version and it worked.